# Android regular expression doesn't match

Tags: java, android, regex, jsoup

Here is something that I don't really understand.

I would like to get the date part from the following string:

```
<th>Elkezdodott</th>
<td>2016. december 20., 19:29</td>
```

So I use the following code:

```
System.out.println(html);
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\p{Punct}th\\p{Punct}Elkezdodott\\p{Punct}{2}th\\p{Punct}\\p{Space}*" +
    "\\p{Punct}td\\p{Punct}" +
    "(\\d{4}\\p{Punct}\\p{Space}*[a-zA-Z]*\\p{Space}*\\d*\\p{Punct}{2}" +
    "\\p{Space}*\\d{2}\\p{Punct}\\d{2})\\p{Punct}{2}td\\p{Punct}");
Matcher m = p.matcher(html);
if(m.matches()){
    System.out.println("matches");
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

This regex seems correct according to the **Check RegExp** option of the **Android Studio**:

[image]

The result of the **System.out.println(html)** is exactly the same as you can see on the image:

```
06-03 11:49:15.779 4581-5229/hu.lyra.moly_kihivasok I/System.out: <th>Elkezdodott</th>
06-03 11:49:15.779 4581-5229/hu.lyra.moly_kihivasok I/System.out: <td>2016. december 20., 19:29</td>
```

What I really don't understand is why **m.matches()** returns false. I also tried **m.find()**, but I got the same result. Did I miss something?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: A little advice that will save you headache later: regular expressions are not the right tool for parsing HTML.

Comment: Thanks. If I don't find any solution I will look for other possibilities. If you have any suggestion don't hold back. :)

Answer (score 1):

I've executed your exact example and it matches the string. The only thing you did wrong, is not passing an argument to the `group()` function. You need to define which group you want to match. In your case, this would be the first one. So, use `group(1);`.

---

Btw. why are you using such a complicated pattern to match your string? I would not use `\p{}` that often, because it makes it unreadable. Just use this:

```
"<th>Elkezdodott</th>\\n<td>(\\d{4}\\.\\s*[a-zA-Z]+\\s*\\d{1,2}\\.,\\s*\\d{2}:\\d{2})</td>"
```

---

Btw.^2 You shouldn't use regex to parse HTML. Use an HTML parser instead. There are plenty around. If you try to parse HTML with regex you are soon coming to major problems (nesting, wrong HTML, like missing end tags etc.).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately changing the argument doesn't change the fact that the m.matches() returns false. And that's what I don't understand, because as you tested online it should work.

Comment: And yes, you are right, I should change it to a HTML parser. And that's what I am going to do. :)